# Javascript remove redundant in multiarray

Tags: javascript, html, multidimensional-array

Need help on processing multidimensional array in javascript.
sample array like below:
start,endtime,name.

```
[04/04/2017 11:00:42,04/04/2018 12:15:37,Nic],
[04/04/2017 11:00:42,04/04/2018 12:16:58,Nic]
```

The result will be like this:

```
[04/04/2017 11:00:42,04/04/2018 12:16:58,Nic]
```

we need compare 2 index first index and last index if match then seconds index as endtime will take from last array.

Below sample code to remove redundant. But, confuse when need to compare more than 1 index and take the last record as result.

```
var compare = new Array();var result = new Array();
for (var y = 0; y < list.size(); y++) {
    if(list.indexOf(list[y][0]) < 0){
        compare.push(listdetails[y][0]);
        result.push(listdetails[y]);
    }
}
```

Anyone can help on this?

Comment: @xianshenglu Yes, correct. compare start and name then take endtime from last record.

[04/04/2017 11:00:42,04/04/2018 12:15:37,Nic],
[04/04/2017 11:00:42,04/04/2018 12:16:58,Nic],
[04/04/2017 11:00:42,04/04/2018 13:16:58,Nic],


result will be
[04/04/2017 11:00:42,04/04/2018 13:16:58,Nic]

Answer (score 1):

One option is to use `reduce` to summarise the data into an object. Use `Object.values` to convert the object to array.

```js
var arr = [
  ['04/04/2017 11:00:42', '04/04/2018 12:15:37', 'Nic'],
  ['04/04/2017 11:00:42', '04/04/2018 12:16:58', 'Nic'],
  ['04/04/2017 11:00:42', '04/04/2018 12:16:50', 'Apple']
];

var result = Object.values(arr.reduce((c, v) => Object.assign(c, {[v[0]+v[2]]: v}), {}));

console.log(result);
```

Comment: Happy to help @shin88

Answer (score 0):

Use `reduce` and `Object.values`

```
//method to get the unique key out of an array item which is also an array
var getKey = ( arr ) => arr[0] + arr[2];
var output = Object.values( arr.reduce( (acc, c) => ( 
     acc[getKey(c)] = c,  //set the latest value with the same key to accumulator
     acc ) , //return the accumulator
{})); //initialize accumulator to {}
```

**Demo**

```js
var arr = [
  ["04/04/2017 11:00:42", "04/04/2018 12:15:37", "Nic"],
  ["04/04/2017 11:00:42", "04/04/2018 12:16:58", "Nic"]
];

var getKey = ( arr ) => arr[0] + arr[2];
var output = Object.values(arr.reduce((acc, c) => (acc[getKey(c)] = c, acc), {}));

console.log( output );
```